# href works on Edge but not on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

`href` won't work in Chrome but it works on Microsoft Internet Explorer or Edge.

Looks like the line (a href="....html")Something(/a) is not working on edge or safari.

It is like dropdown menu.

There is a lot of code. You can check this problem here: http://www.kuhnibelarusi.lv . You will see 4 blue lines. Click on one of them and there will be the dropdown menu.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: inherit;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 4px 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px dashed;
  border-top: 4px solid \9;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 5px; background-color: #3a4d5d; margin: 2px"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="color: white; padding-left: 10px">Pakalpojumi <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/lv/services_design.html">Interjera dizains</a></li>
    <li><a href="/lv/services_kit_designing.html">Virtuves projektēšana</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently your code does not replicate the problem, please update.

Comment: You didn't post any css code that would change the style on `:hover`.

Comment: Just updated the post, sorry for that.

Comment: Please remove the `display: none` and post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like @hungerstar has said. Verify that the link does not work **in your snippet**.

Comment: Code still doesn't produce a verifiable example.

Comment: There is a lot of code. You can check this problem here: http://www.kuhnibelarusi.lv . You will see 4 blue lines. Click on one of them and there will be the dropdown menu.

Comment: Links are working just fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: oh my god! sorry guys! I just check this if it's working on different pc and it is. Looks like my pc is not working properly. ;)))  Thank u guys a lot!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh no! It is not working. I just checked through iPhone safari. Links wouldnt work;(

Comment: Alright, this is the closest i got. Any ideas? It works in snippet but it doesnt work in real life:D

Comment: Then the problem is not part of the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on default browser styles. As you have noticed, they are not reliable.

You also seem to be assuming `href` contains instructions how to style the elements - this is incorrect. `href` only defines the target url of the link.

If you want it to look in a specific way (turn blue, as you said), you have to use own css rules:

```
a,
a:link {
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    color: blue;
}

a:visited {
    color: red;
]
```

Strictly spoken, you only need the second part to make the link turn blue on hover, but if you don't define how it has to look before, you can again get different results in different browsers.

Comment: No I just want that if i click on for example "Interjera dizains" then it would take me to /lv/services_design.html. This works for Edge but not for Chrome. I want it to work on Chrome too.

Comment: @KārlisGustavsLogins why do you talk about the color that does not work in your question. But in this comment you say it is about the problem that clicking on the link wont open the page?

Comment: ? You wrote *"href works on Edge but not on Chrome"* [...] *"would change color when the cursor is hovering it. But on Chrome doesn't change color."* Is that not the question?

Comment: I mean the question is: What i need to do to make href= action work on chrome? Right now it doesnt. The main problem is the href=.  Sorry for my english.:)

Comment: If colors have got nothing to do with your question, remove every mention of color and every css color from your question. Plus everything else that's not of importance. There's a reason it's called **minimal**, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: But the color is also one of the problems. Like color change and href action works on Edge or IE but it doesnt work on Chrome.

Comment: @KārlisGustavsLogins you need to provide a full [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `href` work just fine in Chrome. You likely you have some element overlay issue or similar going on but without a full [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard for us to know what the **real issue** is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Chrome and other browsers that you want a hover state for your 'a' tags, use CSS to do this...

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    color: red;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

you can also style :active and :visited
Try it out =]

Comment: I just updated my post, i have already done that. But the main problem is that the href="" wouldn't work on Chrome

Comment: BAD: .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover
GOOD .dropdown-menu li a:hover

Try that, did it help?

Comment: Why should `>` be bad. It is just more specific. If it is the right choice depends on the usecase.

Comment: Ok i've got it buddy, remove all your inline style. Style your HTML using a separate style sheet, I couldn't change the colours either then when i removed all the inline CSS I saw that the top list item is white so its overwriting other style called before that.

My advice is NEVER use inline CSS. Also your right using > works too, ive just never done that outside jQuery

Comment: Why would jQuery necessitate a child selector over CSS? Seems a bit random.